# How do I cause the first row to be selected when using wxPython DataViewCtrl?

Tags: python

I'm using python 2.6.6 and wxPython.  I have a DataViewCtrl that works great and looks like a table with 6 columns.  It is tied to a data model.  What I would like is so that when someone clicks on the tree to the left and the DVC gets populated (which works already) that the first row (not the heading row) gets selected via code.  Right now the user has to click on the first row to select it and show some relevant data in a different window.  I want it to just be selected for them when the click on the tree on the right.

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured this out.

I had to get all items in my model, then do a

```
self.dvc.SetCurrentItem(item)
```